# Probability related puzzle

Tags: probability

A student has to answer 9 out of 12 questions. How many choices has he if he must answer at least four of the first five questions?

My logic: $^5 C_4$$*$$^7 C_5$+$^5 C_5$$*$$^7 C_4$=$105+35$=$140$

The given answer is $115$. What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he **must** answer to four of the first five question than the answer is:

$${5 \choose 4}{7\choose 5}=105$$

If he needs to answer **at least** four of the first 5 question than you answer is correct, since he can choose to answer 4 of the five question (105 possible solution) or to answer 5 of the first 5 question (35 possible solution):

$${5 \choose 4}{7\choose 5}+{5 \choose 5}{7\choose 4} = 105 + 35 = 140$$